# Show that a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete iff every sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(x_{n+1},x_n) < \infty$, is convergent.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete iff every sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(x_{n+1},x_n) < \infty$, is convergent.

My try: I want to show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(x_{n+1},x_n) < \infty$ holds for a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ then $(x_n)$ is cauchy in $X$.

Let us assume that $(x_n)$ is not Cauchy, $d(x_{n+1},x_n) > c$ thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(x_{n+1},x_n)$ is unbounded. Is the reason correct?? But I am not able to show that it converges in $X$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For $N<m<n$, we have
$$
d(x_m,x_n) \leq
d(x_m,x_{m+1}) + d(x_{m+1},x_{m+2}) + \cdots + d(x_{n-1},x_n) \leq
\sum_{k = N}^\infty d(x_{k},x_{k+1})
$$
In order to prove the other direction of implication (that is, convergence of summable sequences implies completeness), you'll want to take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ and extract a suitable subsequence.  Then, note that Cauchy sequences with a convergent subsequence are convergent.