# How to show that (X,d) is complete iff every sequence ($x_n$) in X with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$d($x_{n+1},x_{n}$) < $\infty$,is convergent?

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Show that (X,d) is complete iff every sequence ($x_n$) in X with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$d($x_{n+1},x_{n}$) < $\infty$,is convergent.

I know that I have to provide what i have tried. But actually i dont find any way to start. Since d($x_{n+1},x_{n}$) converges to 0 as n$\rightarrow$$\infty$ does not imply ($x_n$) is Cauchy. That's where i stuck. If (X,d) is complete so each Cauchy sequence converges to some point in x. But i do not know how to use this facts to show the rest.

[Show that a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete iff every sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(x_{n+1},x_n) < \infty$, is convergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1150711/754079)

The link provides a solution of this question.  I saw that i dont understand what i have to do.

Comment: Tell us what problem you are facing with that proof. Otherwise this question may  be deleted for being  a duplicate.

Comment: If (X,d) be a metric space and ($x_n$) be a Cauchy sequence in X then the sequence is convergent how will that imply $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$d($x_{n+1},x_{n}$) < $\infty$,is convergent?

Comment: And if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$d($x_{n+1},x_{n}$) < $\infty$,is convergent then d($x_{n+1},x_{n}$) converges to 0 as n tend to $\infty$ but that does not imply the sequence is Cauchy so how will i show the converse?

Comment: What can you figure out about the relationship between $d(x_k, x_m)$ and $\sum_{n=k}^{m-1} d(x_n, x_{n+1})$? Start with the case when $m = k+2$.